# Container-fluid dentro de un container (bootstrap)

Tags: bootstrap, css3

Hola buenas tardes a todos, mi consulta es que tengo que hacer que un container tome el 100% del ancho de la pagina (con un color de fondo especifico). Se que no es bueno y no puedo anidar un container-fluid DENTRO DE UN CONTAINER y buscando ejemplos di con lo siguiente:

```
 <!--Contenedor Principal-->
<div class="container">
     
    <!--Seccion Hero Contacto-->
    <section id="heroContacto">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="contact-hero-content" class="col-lg-8">
                    <h1>"La primera regla para obtener éxito es tener una buena preparación"</h1>
                    <p>No dude en contactarnos, tenemos una solución para su necesidad y estamos dispuestos a apoyarlo desde el comienzo, desde el primer contacto.</p>
                </div>

                <div id="contact-hero-button" class="col-lg-4">
                    <a href="#" class="botonHeroContacto">LLAMANOS Y CONVERSEMOS</a> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

y en el css intente con esto

```
#heroContacto{
background-color:#6308c4;    
padding: 30px;
padding-left:0; padding-right:0;
position: relative;
width: 100vw;
left: calc(-1* (100vw - 100%) /2);
```

}

pero me genera un margin al parecer (ver en la imagen el inferior derecho)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias a todos por sus comentarios,

Comment: ¿Quieres centrar el botón verticalmente? No dejas claro que quieres hacer.

Comment: Gracias juan jose por tu tiempo, si dejar el boton centrado vertical y horizontalmente, pero ademas noto que se genera como un descuadre (si miras en la imagen cerca del reloj se nota la barra de desplazamiento del navegador)

Comment: No consigo replicar el problema de la barra vertical. ¿Estás seguro que el problema está en el html que subiste?

Comment: hola juan jose, mira tengo un contendor principal con la clase container, dentro de ese container va el section que debe quedar 100% con color de fondo, seria algo asi: <div class ="container"> <section id="heroContacto">esta es la seccion que tiene el boton y debe quedar 100%, pero que esta generando que aparezca la barra del navegador abajo </section> </div>

Comment: Y porqué no usas `container-fluid` como hijo inmediato del `body` y agregas ahí todo lo demás?

Comment: lo intente y sucede lo mismo

Comment: @NicolasEzequielAlmonacid Yo pongo el código en un entorno, y no me aparece el scroll vertical. Yo creo que se debe a otro contenido del HTML...

Comment: juan jose probe quitando el section y se acomoda bien, lo ingreso de nuevo y aparece el scroll horizontal abajo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optimizando un poco tu HTML (y teniendo en cuenta que a mi no me sucede en mi entorno el problema de la barra vertical), para centrar el botón podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```css
#heroContacto{
    background-color:#6308c4;    
    padding: 30px;
    padding-left:0; padding-right:0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    left: calc(-1* (100vw - 100%) /2);
}

#contact-hero-button{
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto!important;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="heroContacto" class="container-fluid">
            <div  class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="contact-hero-content" class="col-lg-8">
                        <h1>"La primera regla para obtener éxito es tener una buena preparación"</h1>
                        <p>No dude en contactarnos, tenemos una solución para su necesidad y estamos dispuestos a apoyarlo desde el comienzo, desde el primer contacto.</p>
                    </div>

                    <div id="contact-hero-button" class="col-lg-4">
                        <a href="#" class="botonHeroContacto">LLAMANOS Y CONVERSEMOS</a> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

(Ejecutalo en pantalla completa para comprobar que el botón está centrado).
El margin automático y el tamaño de 100% hace que se autocentre el contenido.

¿Es lo que necesitas? Cualquier cosa comenta y lo complemento.

Comment: Juan Jose ahora si desaparece el scrol horizontal y toma el 100% junto con el boton centrado, pero vuelve a aparecer el scrol cuando llego al footer (al final de la pagina) jejeje

Comment: Puedes hacer una cosa, como ahora el problema está en la barra vertical, puedes hacer dos cosas: 1. formular una nueva pregunta o 2. [edit] tu pregunta y añade todo tu codigo HTML (si no es muy extenso) porque si solo te aparece cuando llegas al footer, el problema está ahí (un margin left seguramente).

Comment: GRACIAS al final revisando el css añadi overflow-x: hidden; y ahora funciona como debe...gracias por tu tiempo y colaboracion

Comment: @NicolasEzequielAlmonacid necesitabas centrar un botón y pones en tu título "container-fluid dentro de container"?